# Passing a string variable prop into useQuery function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

**Overview**

App initially queries GraphQL API and renders "Tags" (string) with `TagsList`.

User can then click on a Tag and this Tag is then passed to `ShortList` and rendered.

[image: interface]

**What am I trying to do?**

I have a second GraphQL query named `GQLSIMILARTAGS` This accepts a string variable and is called using `useQuery` in `GQLFuncSecond`.  I want to trigger this when a user click on one of the tags.

I know the query works as I can call it, as follows, with hard coded `searchLabel` which is passed in as a variable.

```
<GQLFuncSecond searchLabel={"cloud"} />
```

**Question**

How do I pass a string (`data.tag.label`) into this `useQuery` variable when the user clicks on a Tag from `TagsList`.

I don't know how I can pass the tag a user selected (when it was added to `ShortList`) into my `GQLFuncSecond` function.

Should I call `GQLFuncSecond` in `ShortList` for example?  How would I do that?

**Main App**

```
function WrappedApp(props) {
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

  function GQLFuncSecond(props) {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLSIMILARTAGS, {
      variables: { search_label: props.searchLabel },
    });
    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

    if (data) return <RelatedTagData data={data.tag} />;
  }

  // add clicked name ID to the favourites array
  const addFavourite = (id) => {
    const newSet = favourites.concat([id]);
    setFavourites(newSet);
  };

  // remove ID from the favourites array
  const deleteFavourite = (id) => {
    const newList = [...favourites.slice(0, id), ...favourites.slice(id + 1)];
    setFavourites(newList);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <GQLFuncSecond searchLabel={"cloud"} />
        <ShortList
          data={props.data}
          favourites={favourites}
          deleteFavourite={deleteFavourite}
        />

        <TagsList
          data={props.data}
          favourites={favourites}
          addFavourite={addFavourite}
        />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default WrappedApp;
```

**Components**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { GQLSIMILARTAGS } from "./graphclient";

/* ##### Single tag ##### */

const Tag = ({ id, info, handleFavourite }) => (
  <li className={info.count} onClick={() => handleFavourite(id)}>
    {info.label} ({info.tag_related_counts_aggregate.aggregate.count})
  </li>
);

const RelatedTagData = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <ul>{data[0].tag_related_counts[0].other_label}</ul>
    <ul>{data[0].tag_related_counts[1].other_label}</ul>
    <ul>{data[0].tag_related_counts[2].other_label}</ul>
    <ul>{data[0].tag_related_counts[3].other_label}</ul>text 
  </div>
);

/* ##### Shortlist ##### */

const ShortList = ({ favourites, data, deleteFavourite, GQLFuncSecond }) => {
  const hasFavourites = favourites.length > 0;
  const favList = favourites.map((fav, i) => {
    return (
      <Tag
        id={i}
        key={i}
        info={data.find((tag) => tag.id === fav)}
        handleFavourite={(id) => deleteFavourite(id)}
      />
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="favourites">
      <h4>
        {hasFavourites
          ? "Shortlist. Click to remove.."
          : "Click on a tag to shortlist it.."}
      </h4>
      <ul>{favList}</ul>
      {hasFavourites && <hr />}
    </div>
  );
};

/* ##### Tag list ##### */

const TagsList = ({ data, addFavourite }) => {
  // Gather list of tags
  const tags = data
    // filtering out the tags that...

    .map((tag, i) => {
      return (
        <Tag
          id={tag.id}
          key={i}
          info={tag}
          handleFavourite={(id) => addFavourite(id)}
        />
      );
    });

  /* ##### the component's output ##### */
  return <ul>{tags}</ul>;
};
```

**GraphQL code**

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql",
});

const GQLTAGS = gql`
  {
    tag(
      order_by: { tag_related_counts_aggregate: { count: desc } }
      where: { label: { _nin: ["None", "null"] } }
    ) {
      id
      label
      tag_related_counts_aggregate {
        aggregate {
          count
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const GQLSIMILARTAGS = gql`
  query($search_label: String!) {
    tag(
      where: { tag_related_counts: { search_label: { _eq: $search_label } } }
      distinct_on: id
    ) {
      label
      tag_related_counts(order_by: { count: desc }) {
        count
        other_label
        search_label
      }
    }
  }
`;


function GQLFunc(props) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLTAGS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  let CallingApp = props.callingApp;
  if (data) return <CallingApp data={data.tag} />;
}
export { client, GQLTAGS, GQLFunc, GQLFuncSecond, GQLSIMILARTAGS };
```

Comment: query `tag` signature ?

Comment: `tag(where.????` .. f.e. from graphiql docs

Comment: @xadm Unfortunately I don't have your level of understanding so don't understand the suggestion. To clarify.  I want to replace current hard coded string ("cloud" in this example) `searchLabel={"cloud"}` with with tag that is passed to `ShortList` (the `data.tag.label`) from this tag.  So if  I click the tag "security" it is currently passed to `ShortList ` but I also want to run the `GQLSIMILARTAGS` query on I this string via `GQLFuncSecond ` function.

Answer (score 1):

### For a while forget about what you have ...

You should pass variables matching to the query shape defined in server

... how is this shape look like? you can read it in graphiql docs

... if `tag` query expects `where` param then you should pass `where` variable (no matter it is a string or complex object - like in this case), just one variable ...

Take a look at "root" variables, `where`, `order_by`, `distinct_on` - all 'input types' defined in graphiql docs for `tag` query.

You should not only replace some query/parameters elements with some [random] 'deeper'/'internal' variables ... it can work but it's quickly became umanageable ... bad DX.

You should prepare `where` object using your `search_label` (prop in this case) and pass `where` as variable. It is not hard to guess your query should look like:

```
query someNameForRelatedTagsQuery($where: where) {
  tag( where: $where ) {
    id
    label
```

Variables object passed to query:

```
const vars = {
  where: { 
    tag_related_counts: { 
      search_label: { 
        _eq: props.search_label
} } } };
```

defined before `useQuery`, used in `useQuery` options `{ variables: vars }` (2nd param)... variables object can be used in lazy query call, too.

How it is related to earlier 'working' hardcoded query? - the same structure, other place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As I already have `tag(where` and variables for `search_label`  in my `GQLSIMILARTAGS` (a query that works in GrpahIQL with variables)  I don't understand how I can use the information provided to help with the question.

Comment: read again, you had to forget about this - once again, forget ... it's missleading

Comment: Can you please show me how to integrate with the code I have.  I don't know where to start.

Comment: You have to learn how to pass variables and this is explained here. If you still don't know then start with simpler example/docs/tutorial ...  After that you should be able to use it in your code.using this hints, this use case related. Just don't stick with what you had hardcoded.

Comment: Perhaps (probably) my question wasn't clear enough.  I've finally got this working and posted my answer.  I used the code I had already with small modifications.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: it was about passing prop into query ... stil you should use only 'root' params, not introducing new variables/params

Answer (score 0):

I can now pass a string (`data.tag.label`) into `useQuery` variable using this approach.  It works but happy to hear of any better approaches.

`useState` to store string label data

```
const [strfavourites, setstrFavourites] = useState([]);
```

Function to be triggered when tag clicked in `ShortList`

```
  const addstrFavourite = (id) => {
    const newSet = strfavourites.concat([id]);
    setstrFavourites(newSet);
  };
```

Add `addstrFavourite`  to `ShortList` component:

```
 handleFavourite={(id) =>
          addstrFavourite(data.find((tag) => tag.id === fav))
```

Only call `useQuery` function if `strfavourites` length > 0

```
const hasstrFavourites = strfavourites.length > 0; 


 {hasstrFavourites &&
      strfavourites.map(function (d) {
        return <GQLFuncSecond key={d.label} searchLabel={d.label} />;
      })}
```